# JavaScript parse bbcode url

Tags: javascript, regex, bbcode

I have been trying for a while to parse bbcode URL tags in JavaScript.

For example,

```
[url=http://examp.le]linktext[/url]
```

should become

```
<a href="http://examp.le">linktext</a>.
```

I have done much research on this and have an awful understanding of regexes.
So the question is, how can I do this?

Comment: If you have done much research on this, you should have at least something which works partly, right? Could you put that in your question?

Comment: I suggest you do not use regex for parsing BBCode as it's very difficult when you have multiple types of tags which may be used wrongly: `[b]bold [u]underlined and bold[/b] wut[/u]`. This should not be parsed like `<strong>bold <u>underlined and bold</strong> wut</u>` since that HTML isn't valid.

Comment: I only need to parse URL tags, but thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this regexp:

```
\[url=([^\s\]]+)\s*\](.*(?=\[\/url\]))\[\/url\]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/A1MnXMtJA8VT1cVD)

So, in JavaScript you can use something like this:

```
text = text.replace(/\[url=([^\s\]]+)\s*\](.*(?=\[\/url\]))\[\/url\]/g, '<a href="$1">$2</a>')
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dd59q/1/)

If you'd like to parse the short format

```
[url]http://ya.ru[/url]
```

which must transform to

```
<a href="http://ya.ru">http://ya.ru</a>
```

You'll need the following regexp:

```
\[url\](.*(?=\[\/url\]))\[\/url\]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Hfa8vSoNjwi6Gy2d)

And the corresponding JavaScript:

```
 text = text.replace(/\[url\](.*(?=\[\/url\]))\[\/url\]/g, '<a href="$1">$1</a>')
```

Comment: I wouldn't do it with regex. BB code needs a parser, since it is a markup with open/end tag similar to HTML.